# Lining amplifiers up in circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I'm struggling to get amplifiers to sit nicely in my circuits. Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw
        (0, 0) node[op amp] (opamp) {}
        (opamp.-) to[R] (-3, 0.5)
        (opamp.-) -- (-1, 2) to[C] (1, 2) -- (opamp.out)
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But this is what it looks like:

[image: tex]

I'm basically having to use trial and error to get those vertical lines to be actually vertical. Surely there is a better way than this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [solution by Gonzalo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228488/21344) works, but in my opinion, it's better to stick with the `circuitikz` bipoles (in this case `short`) so that labeling and connections can be done using the typical `circuitikz` notation if required:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw
  (0, 0) node[op amp] (opamp) {}
  (opamp.-) to[R] (-3, 0.5)
  (opamp.-) to[short,*-] ++(0,1.5) coordinate (leftC)
  to[C] (leftC -| opamp.out)
  to[short,-*] (opamp.out)
;\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

The `-|`/`|-` syntax is very similar, but it uses some labeled coordinates to find the intermediate location.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! What is the `++` syntax?

Comment: @ACarter that is relative coordinate specification. (In this case 1.5 units above the last point on the path.) I use it almost exclusively, because I can grab these snippets and drop them in a new diagram without worrying about updating all the numbers.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `|-` ("first vertical, then horizontal"), `-|` ("first horizontal, then vertical") path modifiers:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw
        (0, 0) node[op amp] (opamp) {}
        (opamp.-) to[R] (-3, 0.5)
        (opamp.-) |- (-1, 2) to[C] (1, 2) -| (opamp.out)
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Connectors can also be added:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw
        (0, 0) node[op amp] (opamp) {}
        (opamp.-) to[R] (-3, 0.5)
        (opamp.-) |-  (-1, 2) to[C] (1, 2) -| (opamp.out)
        ;
    \draw  (opamp.-) to[short,*-] ++(0,0);    
    \draw  (opamp.out) to[short,*-] ++(0,0);    
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, works a treat! Do you know how I can draw nodes at the connections when using `|-`? (As in like you would with `*-*`)

Comment: @ACarter Sure:     `\centering
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw
        (0, 0) node[op amp] (opamp) {}
        (opamp.-) to[R] (-3, 0.5)
        (opamp.-) |-  (-1, 2) to[C] (1, 2) -| (opamp.out)
        ;
    \draw  (opamp.-) to[short,*-] ++(0,0);    
    \draw  (opamp.out) to[short,*-] ++(0,0);    
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{figure}`

Comment: @ACarter but with this new requirement, Paul's approach seems to be shorter and the way to go.