# I'm struggling to line up op amps in circuitkz, any help?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, tikz-circuit-lib, opamp

I saw a [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228486/lining-amplifiers-up-in-circuitikz) which asked this same question but I didn't quite understand the answers properly (I'm new to circuitkz). Also, with such a low reputation I can't make comments to Paul Gessler in order to ask what his solution meant. He answers with the following code

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw
  (0, 0) node[op amp] (opamp) {}
  (opamp.-) to[R] (-3, 0.5)
  (opamp.-) to[short,*-] ++(0,1.5) coordinate (leftC)
  to[C] (leftC -| opamp.out)
  to[short,-*] (opamp.out)
;\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

But I don't understand what leftC is and the (leftC -| opamp.out) coordinate had me very confused. What does leftC do, why did he type in 'coordinate explicitly'? Can someone walk me through the following lines?

```
(opamp.-) to[short,*-] ++(0,1.5) coordinate (leftC)
  to[C] (leftC -| opamp.out)
  to[short,-*] (opamp.out)
```

I am struggling quite a bit to understand what this part of his code does and how it ensures that the op amp is properly lined up with other components in the circuit.

[image: integrator]

Comment: As I see from code, leftC is name of coordinate (name selected by designer of image), which is placed 1.5 cm above amplifier input with name `opamp.-`.  And `(leftC -| opamp.out)` determine point of intersection of horizontal line through coordinate `leftC` and vertical line through `opamp.out`. This syntax is described in TikZ manual and it is not `circuitikz` specific.

Answer (score 4):

```
\draw (opamp.-) to[short,*-] ++(0,1.5) coordinate (leftC)
  to[C] (leftC -| opamp.out)
  to[short,-*] (opamp.out);
```

Starting at node `opamp` anchor `-`, `(opamp.-)`, draw a `short` (as in short circuit) to a location 1.5cm above
and create a coordinate named `(leftC)` here.
Also, draw a thick dot at the starting location.
Draw a capacitor between `(leftC)` and a point horizontally aligned to `(leftC)` and vertically aligned to `(opamp.out)`.
Draw a line from here to `(opamp.out)` and add a thick dot there.

A coordinate is a type of node with only one anchor point: `center`.

Note, `+(0,1.5)` would draw the same line, but `(leftC)` would be located at `(opamp.-)`.

Answer (score 4):

As supplement to John Kormylo's answer:

[image]

Coordinate names `opamp.-`, `opamp.+` and `opamp.out` are composed from name of operational amplifier (OA) `opamp` and defined its anchors (`.-`, `.+` etc) determined with `circuitikz`'s symbol for OA. For its description see manual of `circuitikz' manual.

For more details, how the other coordinates in circuit have been determined, please read section "Specifying Coordinates" in third chapter of TikZ & PGF manual "TikZ ist kein Zeichenprogramm".

I hope that above image will help you in understanding, how your images has been drawn.